# The energy eigenstates $\psi_n(x)$ are eigenstates of parity operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, operators, eigenvalue, parity

> For one dimensional system system described by symmetric potential
>   energies with the property $V(x)=V(-x)$, the energy eigenstates
>   $\psi_n(x)$ are eigenstates of parity operator?

Is the above statement correct? If no, what is the counter example?

I do not have much knowledge about QM. I'm a Mathematician,trying to learn Quantum mechanics on my own.

Comment: https://users.physics.ox.ac.uk/~palmerc/QMfiles/QM5.pdf You should read that. As a math guy you'll have no problem understanding it.

Answer (score 2):

That's not necessarily correct. Consider the potential

$$U(x)=A\cos(x)$$

and boundary conditions

$$\psi(+a)=\psi(-a),$$
$$\psi'(+a)=\psi'(-a)$$

for some $a\in\mathbb R$.

The potential is symmetric, so there *exist* simultaneous eigenstates of both the Hamiltonian $\hat T+\hat U$ and the parity operator. But most of the eigenstates of this Hamiltonian are twice degenerate, so one can form linear combinations of the eigenstates corresponding to the same eigenvalue to get the states that are eigenstates of the Hamiltonian, but not of the parity operator.

Even simpler example:

$$U(x)=\mathrm{const},$$

with the same boundary conditions. The eigenfunctions can be written in the form $\exp(\pm ikx)$ or in the form $B\cos(kx)+C\sin(kx)$. From this you can easily see that the latter form can become an eigenstate of the parity operator (when $B=0$ or $C=0$), while the former can't.

Comment: Just as a footnote: it’s always possible to transform in to a basis that is simultaneous eigenstate of both the operators when they commute.